# Intellij: Regular Expression failed to match - produced stack overflow when matching content of the file

Tags: regex, xml, intellij-idea, stack-overflow

I wanna delete `CDATA` from my filter tag in many .xml files via Intellij Replacement Tool with the following regex.

Search: `<filter>(?:\s)*<!\[CDATA\[((?:\s|\S)*?)]]>(?:\s)*<\/filter>`

Replace: `<filter>$1<\/filter>`

```
<filter><![CDATA[CONTENTX]]></filter> // from
<filter>CONTENTX</filter>             // to
```

If I open the tool with ctrl + shift + f and enter the regex a stack overflow error occurs.

```
Regular expression failed to match
(?:\s)*(?:\s)*\/filter> produced stack overflow when matching content of the file C:/Users/...
```

Comment: Never use `(\s|\S)*` when all you mean is `(?s).*`. Also, `(?:\s)*` = `\s*`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew for your explanation and how to do it better, but I cannot change the expression for business reasons. I increased the jvm stack with the following command `-Xss40m`.